# Nginx not outputting correct chunked responses

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, chunked

I have a backend with expressjs making partial responses on some endpoints.

the pseudocode is something like that:

```
function (req, res, next) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  request.a.file(function response (middleChunk) {
    res.write(middleChunk);
  },
  function final (endingChunk) {
    res.end(endingChunk);
  });
}
```

using curl -v directly to the expressjs instance works like a charm, showing messages progressively and **in the end** the `endingChunk`;

But i'm not using expressjs directly on my hosting, but i'm using a reverse proxy made with nginx, it's configuration it's like that:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name funnyhost;
  root /directory;

  location ~/api/.* {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

Putting on `proxy_buffering off` made the server respond with something:

```
~$ curl -v "domain.com/api/endpoint?testme=true"
* About to connect() to domain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying XX.XX.XX.XX... connected
> GET /api/endpoint?testme=true HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: domain.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2013 17:43:45 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.5.3
< X-Powered-By: Express
<
```

but Nginx awaits for the FULL progress, until the expressjs code reaches `res.end()` before sending the data to the client!

I'm reaching desperate level, i'm wasting hours on this to work :( 
Hope someone could help

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATIONS**

I'm using:

```
~# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.5.3
```

ubuntu 12.04 LTS server, node.js v0.10.15, express 3.3.5

**As requested**

```
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.5.3
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre-jit --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-ipv6 --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-openssl=/build/buildd/nginx-1.5.3/debian/openssl-1.0.1e --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.5.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.5.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.5.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.5.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.5.3/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge
```

**News**

I'm trying to contain the possibilities, so i'm using this script https://gist.github.com/mrgamer/6222708

and the following nginx config file https://gist.github.com/mrgamer/6222734

Making the requests in localhost, everything works smoothly, making the requests to my remote VPS the response headers have different order, and different behaviour; the response gets printed out all togheter.

my local pc and remote VPS have both ubuntu 12.04 with chris lea nginx PPA (launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/nginx-devel), for testing purposes i executed on both:

```
~# sudo aptitude purge nginx nginx-common && sudo aptitude install nginx -y
```

the "strange" behaviour is listed below

**localhost test** headers are in the corrected order and response is correctly progressive

```
~$ curl -v localhost.test
* About to connect() to localhost.test port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost.test
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.5.3
< Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2013 16:04:19 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Chunked transfer encoding test</title></head><body><h1>Chunked transfer encoding test</h1><h5>This is a chunked response after 2 seconds. Should be displayed before 5-second chunk arrives.</h5>
* Connection #0 to host localhost.test left intact
* Closing connection #0
<h5>This is a chunked response after 5 seconds. The server should not close the stream before all chunks are sent to a client.</h5></body></html>
```

**remote test**

```
~$ curl -v domain.com
* About to connect() to domain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying XX.YY.ZZ.HH... connected
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: domain.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2013 16:06:22 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.5.3
< 
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Chunked transfer encoding test</title></head><body><h1>Chunked transfer encoding test</h1><h5>This is a chunked response after 2 seconds. Should be displayed before 5-second chunk arrives.</h5>
* Connection #0 to host test.col3.me left intact
* Closing connection #0
<h5>This is a chunked response after 5 seconds. The server should not close the stream before all chunks are sent to a client.</h5></body></html>
```

Comment: Please, show `nginx -V`. Do you have any 3rd-party modules compiled in nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that was a personal connection problem :)

I was using a 3G network, and my provider (Italian TIM, bleh!) uses some transparent proxies that re-ordered headers and cached responses.

They also block websockets on port 80, so it's no news they are unable to provide an useful experience to their clients.

Sorry serverfault !